# Change the hover border color in an experience cloud

Tags: css, experience-cloud

I am not very familiar with CSS and experience clouds so I apologize if I ask a silly question.
I wanted to run a screen flow in a public experience cloud site. Everything is working fine so far. However while using a specific input component in the site, the border is rendered in blue instead of orange.
[![hoover border rendered in blue][1]][1]

What I wanted to achieve is that the border is rendered in orange. I managed to find the CSS in chrome developer tools.
[image: border in orange]
How can I modify the CSS of the experience cloud so the border will be rendered in orange?

Comment: Hi @Andreas just wondering if you ever found a solution for this? I am trying to solve exactly the same problem.

Comment: Hi @DanMoore up to now I didn't figure out how to solve the issue. Fortunately this is just a proof of concept.